# How can I publish Power BI Report to a website

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I need to do reporting for my client and are looking into Power BI.  What I need to do, is create the report and publish it to the client's website for the public.  These reports are public knowledge, there is no security risk to distribute it.
The users should be able to see the report on the website and use some filtering options that comes with Power BI.
I have installed Power BI Desktop (free option) and created the report, but I can not 'Save as' to Web - there is no such option.
My questions are:

1. Do I need a licence to be able to publish to the web.
2. Once published to the web, will it be displayed on the website to the users with the functionality to filter and drill down even if they do not have Power BI license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options - [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) and to use the API to [embed for your customers (a.k.a. app owns data)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core).

In both cases you must publish the report to Power BI Service. You will need an account for that, but even the free one will work for `Publish to web` case. However, it is way more limited that the actual embedding using the API.

To register an account, you will need a "business e-mail address", i.e. GMail, Outlook, etc. will not work. This is required, because it will create a tenant for this domain, where the administrators in your organization can manage it.

For `Publish to web` the administrator must [explicitly enable that option in the admin portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-portal#publish-to-web). Embedding using the API require programming skills, and normally you will need to buy a "dedicated capacity" (i.e. [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/) or [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/)).

Comment: Thank you Andrey, but what I gather from your answer is that we need some sort of a license either way to have access to publish to the web?  Because the client has no 365 licenses at all, they have everything still on site.

Comment: You must sign up to Power BI to use the service.